# Categories pages showing different layout

Tags: static-block, grid-layout, category-listing

I am trying to figure out 2 catalogs which has different layout, one uses a static block and one nothing (normal).
 I tried disabling the block but now my category on front end is blank. 
Shouldn't it fallback to default view if i disabled the block?
 How can i get my category view back when i click on it. 

Edit: upon searching, i found this that is loading the block, how can i remove it to simply output the page for that catalog.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('men-landing-page')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go in admin and check Category TAB "Is Anchor" Yes or No.

[image]

And Then check Custom Design TAB. 
Then check Page Layout Must be same for all category for same layout.

[image]

Hopefully it will work

Comment: I updated my question, i found some block being loaded.

Comment: Please see the next Answer.
Maybe it will HELP You.

Comment: @surdender can u tell what this mean <a href="{{store url=''}}men?clothing_style=694">, i cannot understand clothing_style=694

Comment: {{store url=''}} = this mean store base URL.
 
 men = adding with url.

?clothing_style=694 = this is query string may be you are passing ID or something in URL

Comment: or Can you specify exactly What is this issue, query string issues or static block issue or category layout issue ?   @  Mr. Nofel

Answer (score 0):

No Need to write this code `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('men-landing-page')->toHtml(); ?>` in .phtml file.

You can get any static block at specific category page on front.

Go in *Admin > Catalog > Manage Categories* open a specific category in which you need show static block:

1. Select here Static block and prodcuts:

   [image]
2. Select here static block which one you want to show at list Page:

   [image]

Follow these steps and show static block on front category list page for particular category without any coding.